# Can we pass soundpool id from one activity to other?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, soundpool

I am new to android. I am working on an app, where i'll need to load many soundpools for different activities.
My question is can we load all soundpools in a single activity and pass that id to different activites where ever tis needed in bundles? (Intenet).

Or is there any other way to do it?

(Goal is to reduce time it takes to load same soundpools in different activities)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want only the id to be passed from one activity to another activity or the entire sound pool object?

Comment: 'm not sure about it so.. 
Which ever makes the soundpool play without having to load again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override/implement the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)  class, in your application, Where you can load your soundpools and in your other activities call [getApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29)

Comment: Working Great! Thanks a lot for help :)